# re-parked domain at godaddy and assigned A record, domain is not refreshed for everyone

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, a-record, domains, domain-parking

I had a domain that was parked at linode.
I moved it back to godaddy and parked it there. then i My A record "@" have the ip value of my new server.

it has been more then 10 hours since then, for some computers this works and they get the new website on the new server. for other computers (asked friends around the world) it isn't updating.. and they still get the old server with old website.

anyway I can hurry this process up? will it get updated eventually for everyone?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's not just client side cacheing? Have them flush their DNS cache.

Comment: general rule of thumb: allow 48 hours for DNS changes to take effect.

Comment: Bryan : the typical value is much shorter now. 48h is now more an urban legend than a measured fact

Comment: guy schaller : impossible to know with so little details. Give the domain name and we can run dig to see the TTL, the state of various caches, the synchronization of authoritative name servers, etc. Otherwise, we can just guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot, each DNS server has its own setting to refresh their cache and you can add to this local DNS caches stored on the computer. You only have to wait.

Comment: -1 because the duration of stay in the caches is *not* controlled by the cache but by the authoritative server which sets the TTL (time to live).

Comment: But +1 because any DNS server is free to ignore these.  Many ISPs set their servers to ignore TTLs which they consider to be too low.